# Как реализовать двойной клик по QPushButton в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qpushbutton

Подскажите как реализовать **`двойной клик`** по `QPushButton`. 
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Ответ на Ваш вопрос в англоязычном сегменте:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987166/pyqt5-qpushbutton-double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987166/pyqt5-qpushbutton-double-click)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> void QWidget::**mouseDoubleClickEvent**(QMouseEvent *event)
>
> Этот обработчик событий для события события может быть повторно реализован в подклассе для получения событий двойного щелчка мыши для виджета.
>
> Реализация по умолчанию вызывает mousePressEvent().
>
> Примечание. Виджет также будет получать события нажатия и отпускания мыши в дополнение к событию двойного щелчка. И если другой виджет, который перекрывает этот виджет, исчезает в ответ на события нажатия или отпускания, то этот виджет получит только событие двойного щелчка. Разработчик должен убедиться, что приложение правильно интерпретирует эти события.